# Dynamically import a modules not known at compile time

Tags: ballerina

#### Scenario:

I have compiled package ".bala" files that the users create. These .bala files are pushed into a repository for my program to import from. The names of the .bala packages are unknown to my program at compile time. The name comes as an input from the user at runtime.

#### Ques

How can I achieve this?

i.e. How can I do something like `import X; // where X is a user defined variable that is assigned a value at runtime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Ballerina at the moment doesn't have a way to dynamically load modules. I think best bet for you would be to take a code-gen approach.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to any examples of code-gen in ballerina?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of any "proper" sample code for this.

Comment: Code generators are a compile-time feature and are not designed for this. It's still a ballerina code with the difference being that it is compiler-generated and added to the package during compilation.

Comment: @AsmaZinneeraJabir is there user facing code-generators available in Ballerina? I can't find any documentation. I was suggesting to manually code-gen and re-compile as I don't see any other way to accommodate this requirement OP asked.

Comment: We have not added any documentation since there are some limitations and we want to redesign it. See https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/1191. Nevertheless, it cannot cater to this requirement with code generators since the code won't compile with an unknown import.